# Generate table cells with random background color, then display hex value of background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm very new to JavaScript...

I've gotten both functions working separately

Here is a js fiddle where I've gotten the table cell to display its background color:

http://jsfiddle.net/chulps/DCaQb/1321/

```js
var colorX = '';
$('td').html(function() {
  var x = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
  hexc(x);
  $("td").html(colorX);
})

function hexc(colorval) {
  var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
  delete(parts[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
    if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
  }
  colorX = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #abcdef; color: white;"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is a js fiddle where I've gotten a table to add a new row and cell on button click:

https://jsfiddle.net/chulps/jfr4d5cc/7/

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }//a
  return color;
}

function setRandomColor() {
  $("td").css("background-color", getRandomColor());
}

var cnt = 1;

$("#anc_roll").click(function () {
  setRandomColor(); 
});

$("#anc_add").click(function () {
  $('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr><td style="background-color:' + getRandomColor() + '">' + '[' + cnt + ']</td></tr>');
  cnt++;
});

$("#anc_rem").click(function () {
  if ($('#tbl1 tr').size() > 1) {
    $('#tbl1 tr:last-child').remove();
  } else {
    alert('One row should be present in table');
  }
  
  if ($('#tbl1 tr').size() > 1) {
    $('#tbl1 tr:last-child').remove();
  } else {
    alert('There has to be at least one color');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 
</head> 
<body class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id='anc_add'>Add Row</a></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id='anc_rem'>Remove Row</a></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id="tbl1" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td>#FFFFFF[#]</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    </div>
  </footer>
  
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to make it all work together
how do I generate the rows with new random background colors **and** display the hex value of the newly generated colors within each cell?

Answer (score 1):

In your first fiddle, you are grabbing the backgroundColor style property from the td element already in the dom, converting it to hex rgb, and then setting that hex value as the html content of the TD element.

In your 2nd fiddle, you're creating a random hex color in `getRandomColor()`. In `#anc_add.click()` you create a new `tr` and `td` dom element w/ the `background-color` set to the value returned by `getRandomColor()` which you are calling directly. Two things to note here.

1. Because you are creating the dom element that you add (in `#anc_add.click()`), you do not need to fetch the element's *background-color*  and convert it to hex - you can just set it outright (which you're doing)
2. you do not need to fetch the element's `background-color` property, convert it to hex, and then add it to the element's HTML after it's already in the dom, like in your first fiddle - you can simply set that when you create the element in `#anc_add.click()`. So you don't need the first fiddle at all.

The quickest fix is to just put the value of `getRandomColor()` in a `var` inside `#anc_add.click()` and then reference the `var` in both the `background-color` and inner HTML of the `td`

`$("#anc_add").click(function(){
    var color = getRandomColor()
    $('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr><td style="background-color:' + color + '">' + '[' + cnt + '] - ' + color + '</td></tr>');
    cnt++;
});`

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/speakingcode/untkx6k5/8/

Comment: this is the correct answer, i can't mark it correct bc i don't have enough rep points on stack overflow but it worked exactly how i wanted it to. Thanks @speakingcode !

Answer (score 0):

In your function `getRandomColor()` you have a syntax error.

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }a <------ Right Here

  return color;
}
```